# When to apply $\frac{mv^2}{r} = q .v .B$

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

A charged particle of mass $m$ is moving with a speed $u$ in a circle of radius $r$ . If the magnetic field induction at the centre is $B$ and the charge on particle is $q$. I want to know why I can't apply:
$$\frac{mu^2}{r} = q .u .B $$

Comment: I think the question is asking about the B field induced by the particle, not a B field that keeps the particle in its circular trajectory. So you should calculate the current and use Biot-Savart's Law.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the electron's motion due to the magnetic field or the magnetic field due to the electron's motion?

Answer (score 1):

$$m\frac{v^{2}}{r}=qvB$$ is applied when the **centripetal** force is provided by the magnetic field.

you question says that the magnetic field is only present at the center,since the rotating particle is not moving **through**  the magnetic field but **around** it ,there is no force acting on the particle due to the magnetic field(some other force must be providing the centripetal force like a string)